# Get an error when want to insert 2 arguments and when it is only one it's okay

Tags: android, sqlite

Hey guys can someone tell me why my method addAlarm works when I add only single "alarm" and when I want to add some name for my alarm I get an error that says `no such column: alarmname  (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT or replace INTO alarms (alarm,alarmname) VALUES(1459006407264,alarmname)` here I wanted to add an alarm that have a name "alarmname". How can fix this?
This is how I create table:

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_ALARMS + "("
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY , " + KEY_ALARM + " TEXT, "
                +  KEY_NAME + " TEXT" + ")";
        db.execSQL("create table alarms ("
                + "id integer primary key,"
                + "alarm text,"
                + "name text," // added a ','
                + "alarmname text" + ");");
    }
```

And my addAlarm method:

```
void addAlarm(Alarm alarm) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        String sql =
                "INSERT or replace INTO alarms (alarm,alarmname) VALUES("+ alarm.getAlarm() + ","+ alarm.getName() + ")" ;
        db.execSQL(sql);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }
```

Comment: Can you try to uninstall the app then try to run it again? From what I gather from your error, you might have modified your model and you did not update your database correctly.

Comment: @gj You mean uninstall on emulator?

Comment: yes, I'm not sure how you do it in emulator, but try to hold click the app icon, then drag to uninstall in upper right corner of screen

Comment: @gj I've uninstalled it and run it again but this didn't give me anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name of the alarm is a string literal, so it should be surrounded by single quotes (`'`s):

```
String sql =
    "INSERT or replace " +
    "INTO alarms (alarm,alarmname) " +
    "VALUES("+ alarm.getAlarm() +  ",'" + alarm.getName() + "')";
    // Here -------------------------^ And here -------------^
```

Comment: Sorry again, you was right all I had to do was to add literals and set DATABASE_VERSION to 2